# Initialize form values from Backend

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I have following service to fetch data. I'm getting data as expected

```
export class UserService {
user: User
    private userSource = new Subject<User>();
    currentUser = this.userSource.asObservable();

constructor(http: Http){}

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot){
      return this.http.get('/getUserData')
        .map(output => {
            console.log("IN RESOLVE. OUTPUT = ");
            console.log(output as User);        // Getting output here as expected
            return output as User;
        })
 }}
```

User Model

```
export clsss User {
constructor(public Basic: {mob: string; email: string},
        public other: {abc: string; xyz: string  }) {}
```

BasicComponent.ts

```
export class BasicComponent implements OnInit {
basicForm: FormGroup;
user: User;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, public userService: UserService) { }

ngOnInit() {
        this.userService.currentUser.subscribe(
            result => {
              console.log(result)
             this.user = result
            })
        this basicForm = this.fb.group({
              mob: [this.user.mob, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)],
              email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, EmailValidator.isValidMailFormat])]
        })
}}
```

I want these values to be prefilled. But `user` object is showing `undefined`.
This is minimal code. I have other components like `BasicComponent` and each of those have `forms`. I've included all dependencies & other declarations. It is working fine except I'm not getting user object in `Formbuilder`

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
export class BasicComponent implements OnInit {
basicForm: FormGroup;
user: User;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, public userService: UserService) { }

ngOnInit() {
        let __self = this;
        this.userService.currentUser.subscribe(result => {
             console.log(result)
             __self.user = result;
             __self contact = __self.fb.group({
                    mob: [__self.user.mob, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)],
                    email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, EmailValidator.isValidMailFormat])]
                });
            });
}}
```

Comment: Where is the difference??

Comment: error: _formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in_

Comment: `basicForm: FormGroup;` and `this contact = this.fb.group` how ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one method**

```
 ngOnInit() {
        // Build the form
        this.basicForm = this.fb.group({
            'business_name' : ['', Validators.required],
            'email'   : ['', Validators.required],
        });
        // Fetch data for the view
         this.userService.currentUser.subscribe(
            result => {
              console.log(result)
             this.user = result

             this.basicForm.setValue({
                business_name: response.data.business.business_name,
                email: response.data.business.email
            });


        })
    }
```